# How to invoke Spring's current property placeholder on resource in java code?

Tags: java, spring, ehcache, placeholder

Spring placeholder mechanism is very clean and robust, unfortunatelly it works only on Spring files.

I'm using **EhCahe** and I want to use the placeholder mechanism on the `ehcache.xml` file. I have my own factory bean for EhCache, and I can give to this library configuration as InputStream. So all I need to do to achieve my goal is:

- read xml file content from classpath
- access the property placeholder **for current spring.xml file** (those in that my bean is configured)
- invoke the placeholder on the read resource
- give the resource back to library as InputStream

So my question is, how to do that, as compact as the Spring allows it? I'd like to avoid creating placeholders itself, so the code will do as little 'magic' as possible, so I'd like to use the property configuration from xml file.

Answer (score 1):

EhCache supports System Property placeholder substitution in the ehcache.xml file, so one option is to copy your Spring placeholder values to System properties so they can be used referenced in the ehcache.xml file:

In spring context xml...

```
<!-- Copy Spring placeholder value to System props -->
<bean id="systemProps" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" value="#{@systemProperties}" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="putAll" />
    <property name="arguments">
        <util:properties>
            <prop key="cache.ttl">${cache.ttl}</prop>
        </util:properties>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Then in your ehcache.xml file you can now use `${cache.ttl}` placeholder populated above:

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd">
    <cache name="myCache" timeToLiveSeconds="${cache.ttl}" maxElementsInMemory="1000" overflowToDisk="false" />
</ehcache>
```

Comment: see: https://vinaycn.wordpress.com/2014/09/02/setup-ehcache-using-springs-property-configurator/

Answer (score 0):

Ehcache has an api to programatically define new caches. Why couldn't you make a bean that starts up along with spring and is filled automagically? That way you don't have to create an automatich EhCache.xml, but you can define all the caches you want in a spring context file.

Comment: You mean rewriting ehcache.xml into spring.xml bean format? It's still an option, however a shocking one for people used to ehcache.xml format, forcing them to learn 'new' one.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to use sytem properties. However you would have to resolve placeholders during build.

Put your properties to object like this:

```
<bean id="cacheProperties" class="java.util.Properties">
    <constructor-arg>
        <props>
            <prop key="prop1">#{prop1}</prop>
            <prop key="prop2">#{prop2}</prop>
        </props>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

And set them to your custom PlaceHolderHelper:

```
    <bean id="cachePlaceholderHelper"
      class="com.PlaceholderHelper" depends-on="cacheProperties">
    <property name="configFileResource" value="classpath:cacheConfig.xml"/>
    <property name="properties" ref="cacheProperties"/>
</bean>
```

PlaceholderHelper could look something like this:

```
private Resource configFileResource;
private Properties properties;
private Resource resolvedConfigResource;

@PostConstruct
public void replace() throws IOException {
    PropertyPlaceholderHelper helper = new PropertyPlaceholderHelper("${", "}");

    if (this.properties != null && this.configFileResource != null) {
        File file = this.configFileResource.getFile();
        String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
        String result = helper.replacePlaceholders(content, this.properties);
        File resolvedCacheConfigFile = new File("resolvedCacheConfig");
        FileUtils.write(resolvedCacheConfigFile, result);

        resolvedConfigResource = new FileSystemResource(resolvedCacheConfigFile);
        logger.info(String.format("Placeholders in file %s were replaced.", file.getName()));
    }
}
```

Change **p:configLocation** to resolved resource:

```
p:configLocation="#{cachePlaceholderHelper.resolvedConfigResource}
```

Now you can use ${prop1} expression anywhere in XML.